# Distinct code wont work SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    U.Unit_ID, P.Plant_ID, P.Project_NR, U.Key_code_list,  
    S.Status_type, Kc.Key_codes4
FROM 
    Plant as P
INNER JOIN 
    Unit as U ON P.Plant_NR = U.Plant_NR
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[Key_code_list] as Kcl ON P.Project_NR = Kcl.Project_NR
INNER JOIN 
    Status_codes as S ON S.Status_nr = Kcl.Status
INNER JOIN 
    Key_codes as Kc ON Kc.Key_code_ID = Kcl.Key_code_list_ID
```

I have this code, and it will give me not the outcome I hoped for. I know it's probably something easy but I've been banging my head against the wall now for an hour and thought why not ask you guys.

The outcome now is:

```
Unit_ID | Plant_ID | Project_NR | Key_code_list | Status_type | Key_code_4 | Key_code _ID
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MEOD    | SM       | 114015     | 4             | Assigned    | AC49       | 11  | 
MLO     | SM       | 114015     | 4             | Assigned    | AC49       | 11  |
MEOD    | SM       | 114015     | 4             | Assigned    | AC47       | 12  | 
MLO     | SM       | 114015     | 4             | Assigned    | AC47       | 12  |
```

The outcome is now twice as a result but that's not correct. I would love to get the answer just once. Can someone please help me?

The desired outcome is :

```
  MEOD    | SM       | 114015     | 4             | Assigned    | AC49       | 12  | 
  MLO     | SM       | 114015     | 4             | Assigned    | AC47       | 11  |



SELECT * FROM dbo.Key_Code_List WHERE Project_NR = '114015'

Key_code_list | Status | Plant_ID | Textfield_unit | Unit_ID | Key_code_list_ID | Project_NR
4             | 2      | SM       | NULL           | MLO     | 11               | 114015
4             | 2      | SM       | NULL           | MEOD    | 12               | 114015
```

Comment: I dont see any duplicate rows.Remember DISTINCT aplies to all columns, not just one

Comment: Are you sure that last JOIN is right?  `kcl.key_code_list_id` might not match to `key_code_id` - based solely on name, they sound like two different items.

Comment: The rows aren't duplicate. The unit_id is meod or mlo and then the rest of the columns are the same.

Comment: No @JChao, the Key Code ID is different ... 11 and 12

Comment: With the new column's results added, `DISTINCT` is doing exactly what you told it to.  Each `unit_id`/`plant_id`/`project_nr`/`key_code_list`/`status_type`/`key_codes4` combination is distinct.  If you want to dedupe using a different criteria (such as ignoring `key_code_id` then you need to either A) not include that column on the output or 2) use ROW_NUMBER() then dedupe manually.

Comment: DISTINCT works on the whole selected row, not just the first select list item.

Comment: @AHiggins I see that but I was just saying assuming he thinks the first 2 rows should only be 1 row. Same for the last 2.

Comment: Whats is the criteria why for MEOD, key_code 11 and not 12?Same for MLO..

Comment: It sounds like one of your joins are bad. Probably the KCL one. It's hard to help without knowing the structure and data in the tables.

Comment: Please edit your question with the results of the following query: `SELECT * FROM dbo.Key_Code_List WHERE Project_NR = '114015'`

Comment: @AHiggins there you see the results.

Comment: Note that neither of the desired rows is even among the rows you actually observe.

Comment: @NickvanderDeijl, the results clearly show that the `Project_NR` that you are showing has two associated `Key_Code_List_ID` values, `11` and `12`.  You either need to eliminate that column from your result set, pick one of the rows in the `Key_Code_List` table to use, or accept the fact that you will have two records, one for each of the values.

Comment: This join looks suspicious: `INNER JOIN Key_codes as Kc ON Kc.Key_code_ID = Kcl.Key_code_list_ID`.  Not having any special knowledge of the meanings of of these columns, I would suppose that that a `Kcl.Key_code_list_ID` identifies a particular *list* of key codes, whereas a `Kc.Key_code_ID` identifies a particular key code such as might appear *in* a key code list (not *as* a key code list).

Comment: @AHiggins if I remove the Key_code_list_ID column the result is the same only without the Key_code_list_ID

Comment: Looking at the result of Key_Code_list why are you joining Plant and Unit tables when the data is in Key_Code_List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the Unit_ID field in the join to the Key_Code_List table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    U.Unit_ID, P.Plant_ID, P.Project_NR, U.Key_code_list,  
    S.Status_type, Kc.Key_codes4
FROM 
    Plant as P
INNER JOIN 
    Unit as U ON P.Plant_NR = U.Plant_NR
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[Key_code_list] as Kcl ON 
        P.Project_NR = Kcl.Project_NR AND 
        U.Unit_ID = Kcl.Unit_ID -- add this to the JOIN condition
INNER JOIN 
    Status_codes as S ON S.Status_nr = Kcl.Status
INNER JOIN 
    Key_codes as Kc ON Kc.Key_code_ID = Kcl.Key_code_list_ID
```

Comment: Happy to help. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.